# Using custom StyleGAN2-ada network in GANSpace (.pkl to .pt conversion)

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, stylegan

I trained a network using [Nvdia's StyleGAN2-ada pytorch implementation](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2-ada-pytorch). I now have a .pkl file. I would like to use the [GANSpace code](https://github.com/harskish/ganspace) on my network. However, to use GANSpace with a custom model, you need to be able to give it a checkpoint to your model that should be uploaded somewhere (they suggest Google Drive)(checkpoint required in code [here](https://github.com/harskish/ganspace/blob/master/models/wrappers.py#L138)). I am not entirely sure how this works or why it works like this, but either way it seems I need a .pt file of my network, not a .pkl file, which is what I currently have.

I tried following this [tutorial](https://github.com/dvschultz/ai/blob/master/Ganspace_S2DD.ipynb). It seems the GANSpace code actually provides a file (models/stylegan2/convert_weight.py) that can do this conversion. However, it seems the file convert_weight.py that was supposed to be there has been replaced by a link to a whole other [repo](https://github.com/harskish/stylegan2-pytorch/tree/91ea2a7a4320701535466cce942c9e099d65670e). If I try run the convert_weight.py file as below, it gives me the following error

```
python content/stylegan2-pytorch/convert_weight.py --repo="content/stylegan2-pytorch/" "content/fruits2_output/00000-fruits2-auto1/network-snapshot-025000.pkl"

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnnlib'
```

This makes sense because there is no such dnnlib module. If I instead change it to look for the dnnlib module somewhere that does have it ([here](https://github.com/skyflynil/stylegan2)) like this

```
python content/stylegan2-pytorch/convert_weight.py --repo="content/stylegan2/" "content/fruits2_output/00000-fruits2-auto1/network-snapshot-025000.pkl"
```

it previously gave me an error saying TensorFlow had not been installed (which in all fairness it hadn't because I am using PyTorch), much like this error reported [here](https://github.com/rosinality/stylegan2-pytorch/issues/250). I then installed TensorFlow, but then it gives me this error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch_utils'
```

again the same as in the previous issue reported on github. After installed torch_utils I get the same error as SamTransformer (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch_utils.persistence'). The response was "convert_weight.py does not supports stylegan2-ada-pytorch".

There is a lot I am not sure about, like why I need to convert a .pkl file to .pt in the first place. A lot of the stuff seems to talk about converting Tensorflow models to Pytorch ones, but mine was done in Pytorch originally, so why do I need to convert it? I just need a way to upload my own network to use in GANSpace - I don't really mind how, so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, the conversion script provided was to convert weights from the official Tensorflow implementation of StyleGAN2 into Pytorch. As you mentioned, you already have a model in Pytorch, so it's reasonable for the conversion script to not work.

Instead of StyleGAN2 you used StyleGAN2-Ada which isn't mentioned in the GANspace repo. Most probably it didn't exist by the time the GANspace repo was created. As far as I know, StyleGAN2-Ada uses the same architecture as StyleGAN2, so as long as you manually modify your `pkl` file into the required `pt` format,you should be able to continue setup.

Looking at the [source code for converting to Pytorch](https://github.com/harskish/stylegan2-pytorch/blob/91ea2a7a4320701535466cce942c9e099d65670e/convert_weight.py#L233), GANspace requires the `pt` file to be a `dict` with keys: `['g', 'g_ema', 'd', 'latent_avg']`. StyleGAN2-Ada [saves a `pkl` containing a `dict`](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2-ada-pytorch/blob/6f160b3d22b8b178ebe533a50d4d5e63aedba21d/training/training_loop.py#L357) with the following keys: `['G', 'G_ema', 'D', 'augment_pipe']`. You *might* be able to get things to work by loading the contents of your `pkl` file and resaving them in `pt` using these keys.